# Differences between GAMLSS GLM and linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, glm, gamlss

I'm actually studing GAMLSS models (genralized additive models for location, scale and shape). My question is: It's correct to say that those models are a generalization of GLM and Linear regression? If I use GAMLSS with an exponential family distribution and Identity link function over sigma I obtain GLM? And as special case if I use Normal distribution and two Idenity link functions I obtaine a Linear Regression?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The gamlss model is a generalization of both GLM and linear regression models.

If you use e.g. gamlss(y~x,family=NO) you are fitting a normal distribution NO(mu, sigma), (the default in gamlss).
Also by default the sigma is constant
and by default the link function for mu for NO is the identity.
So you have a linear regression model.

For a GLM, e.g. a gamma distribution, GA(mu,sigma),
gamlss(y~x,family=GA)
again by default the sigma is constant,
and by default the link function for mu for GA is the log.
So you have a GLM with a gamma error
(although I think the default mu link for a gamma in a GLM using the R glm() and gam() is the inverse).

Note however gamlss() fits the model using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE), so the estimated sigma is a MLE.
I think glm() and gam() may have a different default estimator of sigma,
and it also uses a dispersion parameter = sigma^2.